# Android - Scrollable ImageView Lag

Tags: android, scroll, imageview, lag

I am using the Scrollable ImageView [by Egor Andreevich found here](http://egorand.blogspot.de/2013/03/a-simple-implementation-of-scrollable.html).

Although I have successfully managed to insert this into my app, the issue I'm having is that my image is very laggy. The image I'm using is **1.63 mb** and **3713x3329** in dimension. If I use a smaller image that is both small in dimension and size, then it works perfectly.

Comment: Try resizing the width of the image to the width of the screen or container prior to displaying it in the ImageView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The post you are referring to seems to be an introduction of scrolling images in an ImageView, and not a complete implementation. I would direct you to [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) for a more complete implementation.